# D3.js word cloud does not display without error message

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, d3-cloud

I'm trying to make word cloud with d3.js, and when I try to call page the word cloud does not displayed.

However, there is no error message in console so I can't figure out which part is wrong.

The data set looks like this.

```
[{word: "happy", freq: 3}, {word: "apple", freq: 4}]
```

This is my code.

```
 <div id="cloud"></div>
<style>
text:hover {
    stroke: black;
}
</style>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/emeeks/3361332/raw/61cf57523fe8cf314333e5f60cc266351fec2017/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var weight = 3,
      width = 960,
      height = 500;

  var fill = d3.scale.category20();
  var data = {{ data|js }};

  var result = scale(data);

  function scale (data) {
      var result = [];
      for (var k in data){
          var value = data[k];
          result.push({word:value['word'], weight:+value['freq'] * weight});
      }
      return result;
  }

  d3.layout.cloud().size([width, height]).words(result)
      .rotate(0)
      .font("Impact")
      .fontSize(function(data) { return data.size; })
      .on("end", draw)
      .start();

  function draw(words) {
      d3.select("#cloud").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")")
        .selectAll("text")
          .data(words)
        .enter().append("text")
          .style("font-size", function(data) { return data.size + "px"; })
          .style("font-family", "Impact")
          .style("fill", function(data, i) { return fill(i); })
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("transform", function(data) {
            return "translate(" + [data.x, data.y] + ")rotate(" + data.rotate + ")";
          })
        .text(function(data) { return data.text; });
    }
```

Comment: You are referring to `value['freq']` in your code. But I could not find that property in your data set objects. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed two issues in your code.

1) The `freq` property is missing in the data set which is currently used to calculate the weight of each node. Since font size depends on the weight attribute, it becomes 0.

2) The result array contains objects having key name as `word`. So either you should override the text method of the cloud layout as shown below OR update the key name to `text`.

```
 d3.layout.cloud()
   ..............
   ..............
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.word;
  })
```

```js
var weight = 3,
  width = 960,
  height = 500;

var fill = d3.scale.category20();
var data = [{
  word: "happy",
  weight: 10,
  "freq": 8
}, {
  word: "apple",
  weight: 4,
  "freq": 3
}, {
  word: "wishes",
  weight: 6,
  "freq": 5
}, {
  word: "sad",
  weight: 5,
  "freq": 2
}, {
  word: "orange",
  weight: 21,
  "freq": 3
}, {
  word: "condolence",
  weight: 3,
  "freq": 2
}];

var result = scale(data);

function scale(data) {
  var result = [];
  for (var k in data) {
    var value = data[k];
    result.push({
      word: value['word'],
      weight: +value['freq'] * weight
    });
  }
  return result;
}

//console.log(result);

d3.layout.cloud().size([width, height]).words(result)
  .rotate(0)
  .font("Impact")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.word;
  })
  .fontSize(function(data) {
    return data.weight;
  })
  .on("end", draw)
  .start();

function draw(words) {
  d3.select("#cloud").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(words)
    .enter().append("text")
    .style("font-size", function(data) {
      return data.size + "px";
    })
    .style("font-family", "Impact")
    .style("fill", function(data, i) {
      return fill(i);
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", function(data) {
      return "translate(" + [data.x, data.y] + ")rotate(" + data.rotate + ")";
    })
    .text(function(data) {
      return data.text;
    });
}
```

```css
text:hover {
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="cloud"></div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/emeeks/3361332/raw/61cf57523fe8cf314333e5f60cc266351fec2017/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
```